# Transpose rows to columns in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have data like this:

[image]

I am trying to transform it to this (using SQLite). In the desired result, within each id, each start should be on the same row as the chronologically closest end. If an id has a start but no end (like id=4), then the corresponding end, will be empty (as shown below).

[image]

I have tried this

```
select 
    id,
    max( case when start_end = "start" then date end) as start,
    max(case when start_end = "end"   then date end ) as end
from df
group by id
```

But the result is this, which is wrong because id=5 only have one row, when it should have two:

```
  id      start        end
1  2 1994-05-01 1996-11-04
2  4 1979-07-18       <NA>
3  5 2010-10-01 2012-10-06
```

Any help is much appreciated

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,start_end VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,date      DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,start_end,date) VALUES (2,'start','1994-05-01');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,start_end,date) VALUES (2,'end','1996-11-04');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,start_end,date) VALUES (4,'start','1979-07-18');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,start_end,date) VALUES (5,'start','2005-02-01');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,start_end,date) VALUES (5,'end','2009-09-17');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,start_end,date) VALUES (5,'start','2010-10-01');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,start_end,date) VALUES (5,'end','2012-10-06');
```

Comment: Please post a dump of your test db. The text which contains the "CREATE TABLE ..." lines. So that we have something to play with.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  s.id        as id,
  s.date      as 'start',
  min(e.date) as 'end' -- earliest end date from "same id&start"
from
  -- only start dates
  (select id, date
   from intable
   where start_end='start'
   ) as s
left join -- keep the start-only lines
  -- only end dates
  (select id, date
   from intable
   where start_end='end'
   ) as e
on      s.id = e.id
  and s.date < e.date -- not too early
group by s.id, s.date -- "same id&start"
order by s.id, s.date; -- ensure sequence
```

- Left join (to keep the start-only line for id "4") two on-the-fly tables, start dates and end dates.
- Take the minimal end date which is just higher than start date (same id, using `min()`and `group by`.
- Order by id, then start date.

I tested this on a test table which is similar to your dump, but has no "NOT NULL" and no "PRIMARY KEY". I guess for this test table that is irrelevant; otherwise explain the effect, please.

Note:
Internally three pairs of dates for id 5 (those that match end>start) are found, but only those are forwarded with the lowest end (`min(end)`) for each of the two different combinations of ID and start `group by ID, start`. The line where end>start but end not being the minimum is therefor not returned. That makes two lines with start/end pairs as desired.

Output (with `.headers on`):

```
id|start|end
2|1994-05-01|1996-11-04  
4|1979-07-18|  
5|2005-02-01|2009-09-17  
5|2010-10-01|2012-10-06
```

UPDATE: Incorporate helpful comments by @MatBailie.

Comment: Wow. Where to start with this?  `GROUP BY id||start` forces an implicit conversion of each field to a string, then concatenate them.  It should be `GROUP BY id, start`, whuch simply groups by two fields.

Comment: `UNION` causes deduplication, and can therefore be expensive.  `UNION ALL` does not deduplicate and should be used in these types of cases.

Comment: `table1, table2 where blahblah` is pre-1992 syntax.  It should be `table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON blahblah`.

Comment: `like "_tart"` should be `= 'start'`

Comment: In the OP there are four records for id=5.  Two starts and two ends.  Your first query will return 3 pairs instead of 2.  `'2005-02-01' -> '2009-09-17'` and `'2005-02-01' -> '2012-10-06'` and `'2010-10-01' -> '2012-10-06'`

Comment: @MatBalie Sorry to contradict, the code I wrote returns (at least on my machine) this: 2|1994-05-01|1996-11-04
4|1979-07-18|
5|2005-02-01|2009-09-17
5|2010-10-01|2012-10-06 I have sqlite 3.18.0

Comment: I tried the `group by ID||start`-> `group by ID, start`, it works. Thanks I learned something.

Comment: I tried the `UNION ALL` it kind of works, just changes the order to 2,5,5,4. This order is not relevant and using `UNION` does not guarantee it either. But I choose to keep the `UNION` in this case. Should order be important and needs guarantees, then a simple `ORDER by ID, start` should fix it. In that case the `UNION ALL` should also be used. @MatBailie Thanks for the details.

Comment: Pre 1992 or not. I confuse the different joins too often. So I write explicitly what I want to happen. I like my code to be understandable to myself after a long vacation on a beach, i.e. I like it self-explaining, to me.

Comment: I did try using `= "start"` instead of `like "_tart"` but that does not work... For reasons unknown to me. I suspect a conflict between some values being "start" and one of the headers in the desired output to be identically "start". @MatBailie Any ideas on how to fix/avoid that?

Comment: Pay careful attention to this; `= 'start'`.  It uses single quotes, not double quotes.  SQLite tries to be helpful and accept double quoted strings where it can, but `"start"` is intended to mean the Field named `start`.  Quoting the field names allows such debauchery as field names with spaces in them.

Comment: Neither `UNION` nor `UNION ALL` guarantee return order.  SQL only ever guarantees that when `ORDER BY` is used.  `SELECT a, b FROM x UNION ALL SELECT a, b FROM y ORDER BY a, b` - the ordering applies to the whole result, not to just the second subquery; This is because ordering the subquery would be pointless (the implementation of the outer query would undo any ordering guarantee), so SQL Syntax applies the UNION first.

Comment: Although pre ANSI-92 confuses you, as soon as you write longer queries or OUTER JOINS with `(+)` notation in the WHERE clause, two things happen; it becomes MUCH harder to read, and the meaning becomes ambiguous.  The second one is really important, it means the SQL Engine has to guess what you mean and gets it wrong.  It's deprecated for that reason; it doesn't actually always work.  You will find that some people down vote pre ANSI-92 answers because it is so bad.  It is industrially accepted that it should NOT be used.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't read the outer query that rationalise two pairs back down to one.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks and my respect for confirming. If you like we can clean up all the references to that. It wouldn't hurt the general look of this...

Comment: @MatBailie I did some reading and got over my (flimsically rationalised) fear of joins. Respectful thanks for forcing me to. I used most of your comments now. We were agreed from start that neither UNION nor UNION ALL guarantee sequence; but it was not required anyway (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to do, only with a few changes:

```
SELECT
  s.value     AS 'url',
  "AVGDATE"   AS 'fieldname',
  sum(e.value)/count(*) AS 'value'
FROM 
  (SELECT url, value
   FROM quicktag
   WHERE fieldname='NAME'
   ) AS s
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT url, substr(value,1,4) AS value
   FROM quicktag
   WHERE fieldname='DATE'
   ) AS e
ON      s.url = e.url
WHERE e.value != ""
GROUP BY s.value;
```

I had a table like this:

```
url         fieldname   value    
----------  ----------  ----------
1000052801  NAME        Thomas 
1000052801  DATE        2007
1000131579  NAME        Morten
1000131579  DATE        2005     
1000131929  NAME        Tanja
1000131929  DATE        2014     
1000158449  NAME        Knud    
1000158449  DATE        2007
1000158450  NAME        Thomas    
1000158450  DATE        2003
```

I needed to correlate NAME and DATE in columns based on url as a key, and generate a field with average DATE grouped by multiple NAME fields.

So my result looks like this:

```
url         fieldname   value      
----------  ----------  ---------- 
Thomas      AVGDATE     2005
Morten      AVGDATE     2005     
Tanja       AVGDATE     2014     
Knud        AVGDATE     2007
```

Unfortunately I not have enough posts to make my vote count yet.